# Parenting Armature and Weights To Mesh Distorts Smooth Shading

Tags: rigging, armature, shaders, smooth, weight-paint-mode

When I parent my skeleton to my smooth shaded mesh with automatic weights, the shading distorts. Messing with weight paints also distorts it.

Why? How do I fix/prevent this? Here's what the model looks like  before and after parenting to the skeleton:

[image: Before applying skeleton to mesh]

[image: After applying skeleton to mesh]

[image: Wireframe]

[image: One of the weights]

Here is the file:

[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "apply my skeleton to my smooth shaded mesh"? Do you mean when you parent your object to the armature? Maybe share your object?

Comment: Uh yeah i thiink that's the terminology, crtrl + p and automatic weights n stuff
Forgot Applying was also a modifier action heh...

Comment: Could you please share your file?

Comment: It should be availabe now *if i did it right*

Comment: Hello Samarium.. the download file may be enough, but I think it might help folks to answer if you illustrated the wire-frame and the weights. Let's wait and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you have overlapping vertices, so select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*:

[image]

Now the bad shading comes from the ngons, you can fix that with a better topology:

[image]

But the *Auto Smooth* alone may be enough:

[image]